# Lombok @Builder.Default isn't working for @Value object if to set null

Tags: java, lombok

I'm trying to get immutable Object that sets default value to all null fields.
So my object is:

```
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Value;

@Value
@Builder
public class Test {
    @Builder.Default
    String name = "default";
}
```

and I expect these two tests to pass:

```
assert Test.builder().build().name == "default"
assert Test.builder().name(null).build().name == "default"
```

but second one isn't passing.

How can I tell lombok not to set actually null in such case?
I have value that comes from another service and it's nullable. I want to use default value if it came null to me.

Comment: Actually it's not valid you pass null then default should not work that's expected

Comment: @User-Upvotedon'tsayThanks ok, so how my issue can be solved?

Comment: Can't you just not call `name(null)`, when you don't want `name` to be `null`? I know it's not what you're asking for, but it makes sense to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lombok's `@Builder.Default` remembers whether the corresponding builder setter method has been called or not. This allows explicitly overwriting the default value even with `null`. There is no built-in way to "unset" the value.

There are two ways to solve this:

1. Remove the default value and `@Builder.Default` from `name`. Then manually implement an all-args constructor that checks whether the parameter `name` is `null` and assign the default value in that case.
2. Customize the builder setter method such that passing `null` will unset it:

```
    public static class TestBuilder {
        public TestBuilder name(String name) {
            this.name$value = name;
            this.name$set = name != null;
            return this;
        }
    }
```

I suggest you use the latter approach, because then you won't have to modify your manual all-args constructor every time you add or remove a field in that class.